# How to change orientation in Android Device Monitor "Dump View Hierarchy"

Tags: android

In Android Device Monitor there is a tool to dump the view hierarchy for UI automator.

I want to debug the UI for a landscape tablet app, but the screenshot is captured in portrait mode, how can I change this to landscape.
The "Screen Capture" option in Android Device Monitor does take a screenshot in landscape mode.

Android Device Monitor: 24.4.1

Device: HTC Nexus 9 running Android 6.0

Comment: I can confirm the bug. I'll post an answer with workaround.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I also have encountered the problem: the screenshot of a device in landscape orientation is displayed vertical in the View Hierarchy window. It's important, that control boundaries are highlighted correctly as if the screenshot has horizontal orientation, but since the image is not rotated accordingly, the highlighting is inconsistent with the image. The only workaround I have found is to rotate the image manually.

DDMS stores view hierarchy dump in a temporary folder. In my case it is located in the following Windows path: `C:\Documents and Settings\User\Local Settings\Temp\uiautomatorviewer_[number]`. You may see the full path in a floating tooltip appearing when you hover your mouse on the `.uix` file tab.

After you noted the path, close the `.uix` tab for a moment.

The folder on the path contains the `.uix` file itself and an image (`.png`). The quick fix is to rotate the image by an applicable program. I did it in Windows with standard tools:

- right click on the image;
- choose **Preview** command;
- in the Preview window use **Rotate Clockwise** (<kbd>Ctrl+K</kbd>);

Now open the `.uix` file anew in the IDE. It will most likely ask you to **Specify screenshot** - press this button and choose the modified `.png` file. Voila.

Comment: Although not ideal the workaround works. I work on Mac OS X, there the screenshot is in some temporary folder. I copied the uix and screenshot, rotated the screenshot and opened the .uix in device monitor.

Answer (score 0):

Apart from the solution(which is not working for Mac Users), you the try this:

1. Take the screen in UIAutomatorViewer
2. Click on Save and save in some location(this will save both .png and .uix file)
3. Go to the saved location and rotate .png file accordingly
4. In UIAutomatorViewer, open that .png file and ta da, you got your app view